# How can I use multiple insert/update/delete queries in a single stored procedure with transaction and rollback

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How can I use multiple insert/update/delete queries in a single stored procedure with transaction and rollback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC (@TBL1 INT, @TBL2 INT, @TBL3 INT, @VALUE INT)
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            UPDATE  TBL1
            SET     COL1 = @VALUE
            WHERE   id = @TBL1

            UPDATE  TBL2
            SET     COL2 = @VALUE
            WHERE   id = @TBL2

            UPDATE  TBL3
            SET     COL3 = @VALUE
            WHERE   id = @TBL3
        COMMIT
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
        END
    END CATCH
END
```